# Java Regex does not match newline

Tags: java, regex

My code is as follows:

```
public class Test {
    static String REGEX = ".*([ |\t|\r\n|\r|\n]).*";
    static String st = "abcd\r\nefgh";

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(st.matches(REGEX));
    }
}
```

The code outputs `false`. In any other cases it matches as expected, but I can't figure out what the problem here is.

Comment: What `[ |\t|\r\n|\r|\n]` actually means is `[ \t\r\n|]`, i.e., one (!) out of the *set* of the characters enclosed in `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

Based on your comments, you need something like this:

```
.*(?:[ \r\n\t].*)+
```

**EXPLANATION**:

**In plain words, it is a regex that matches a** line, then 1 or more lines. Or, just a **multiline text**.

- `.*` - 0 or more characters other than a newline
- `(?:[ \r\n\t].*)+` - a non-capturing group that matches 1 or more times a sequence of

  - `[ \r\n\t]` - either a space, or a `\r` or `\n` or `\t`
  - `.*` - 0 or more characters other than a newline

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hJ9iP4/2)

**Original answer**

You can fix your pattern 2 ways:

```
String REGEX = ".*(?:\r\n|[ \t\r\n]).*";
```

This way we match either `\r\n` sequence, or any character in the character class.

Or (since the character class only matches 1 character, we can add `+` after it to capture 1 or more:

```
String REGEX = ".*[ \t\r\n]+.*";
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/jj4N2y)

Note that it is not a good idea to use single characters in alternations, it decreases performance.

Also note that capturing groups should not be overused. If you do not plan to use the contents of the group, use non-capturing groups (`(?:...)`), or remove them.

Comment: I have a new problem now. The regex won't match on a string with multiple newlines. How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you please provide a sample string and the expected output?

Comment: For a string as "Sample\nString\nNo\nMatch" it outputs false, but I want it to be true aswell.
I guess it's about the "." meaning any character except newline?

Comment: Yes, but you can also use `.*(?:[ \t\r\n]+.*)*`. However, I do not see the point. You can enable dotall with `(?s)`, but what good is `(?s).*`?

Comment: Somehow it now matches any input string I enter.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you are doing, and best if you update the question itself. Why should `Sample\nString\nNo\nMatch` match? What are the criteria? Any string containing whitespace? Then try `.*(?:[ \t\r\n]+.*)+`.

Comment: It's ok I found what I needed. ".*([ \r\n\t].*)+.*". I did not want any whitespaces, nor newlines(it doesn't matter how many).

Answer (score 5):

You need to remove the character class.

```
static String REGEX = ".*( |\t|\r\n|\r|\n).*";
```

You can't put `\r\n` inside a character class. If you do that, it would be treated as `\r`, `\n` as two separate items which in-turn matches  either `\r` or `\n`. You already know that `.*` won't match any line breaks so, `.*` matches the first part and the next char class would match a single character ie, `\r`. Now the following character is `\n` which won't be matched by `.*`, so your regex got failed.